# Throw 403 error after page refresh on NextJS

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, next.js

I have an app with Next.js. It has some routes (pages).
I place the app on the static hosting. Everything works fine, but when I resfersh any page except home page, I get 403 error..
I place the .htaccess in root dir with code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

But no result.
Please help me fix this propblem...